# Why does Java require "new" when it is understood that a constructor creates a new instance

Tags: java, new-operator

I've surfed the web for the Java use of "new", and it is for creating a brand new class instance.  Why does that require explicit indication via the "new" keyword?  Isn't it understood that a constructor invocation instantiates a new object?  Without `new`, for example, it is clear that `MyClass AnInstance = MyClass(AnArgument)` creates a new object.

From a practical perspective, my reason for asking is because I assume that "new" was designed in to guard against a hazard, and I want to be aware of the hazard.

Comment: "Why does language X have syntax Y?" seems a bit off-topic for SO.

Comment: The constructor does not create a new instance. The constructor only initializes it.

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/types-of-classes-in-java

Comment: @Chris: Excuse me, but I am having a senior's moment.  I can't seem to find my way to the SO FAQ that explains what is within scope and what is not.  Maybe the navigation path has changed.  But my reason for asking is because I assume that "new" was designed in to guard against a hazard, and I want to be aware of the hazard.

Comment: See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47678/why-did-memory-managed-languages-like-java-javascript-and-c-retain-the-new

Comment: @user2153235 you might not use the new keyword if the type of class is made static, you can read more about it.

Comment: @MoFarid: You linked to a very fulsome site.  Would you be able to elaborate?  Googling `java what-is-a-static-class` doesn't yield anything that I recognize to be an explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: @yshavit: Thank you for that!  Not coming from a computer science background, I was not aware of the difference between stack and heap.  So that is why `new` is used.

Comment: @user2153235 please, you always can Google your question. https://medium.com/@winwardo/javas-new-keyword-under-the-hood-8b2f0d8c8665

Comment: @MoFarid: As is normal today, Google is the first thing I consulted.

Comment: hmmm, I wonder why you didn't find the answer: https://medium.com/@winwardo/the-new-keyword-in-far-too-many-languages-b98588842783

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an issue of namespaces.

In java, methods and fields can have the same name and they are utterly unrelated. In fact, so can types, and so can packages. All 4 are completely orthogonal. **Never the 4 shall meet**:

```
package foo;

public class foo {
  int foo;

  public foo() { /* constructor */ }

  public void foo() { /* method */ }
}
```

That is *entirely* legit. Nothing overwrites anything here - that's a class named `foo` in package `foo`, with 3 members: A field named `foo`, a constructor that takes zero arguments, and a method named `foo` that takes no arguments and returns nothing. You can compile it. It will. With no warnings. Your IDE will probably complain that it's non-conventional to start a type with a lowercase letter. But that's just convention. The lang spec allows this. `javac` will compile the above just fine.

So, if you can have all these things all named the same thing, how does that work then?

From context java always knows what you are doing.

In some languages, parentheses are optional when invoking methods, or, at least, everything is in the same namespace.

For example, in javascript:

```
function test() {
}

var x = test;
```

Is legal; `x` is now a reference to the `test` function.

It also means you **cannot**, in fact, have a method and a variable with the same name in javascript:

```
function test() {
}

test = 5;
test();
```

Does not work. That last statement attempts to execute '5' as a function which it is not.

In java this is not the case (those parens aren't optional, and without the parens, it just isn't about that method, period), because java is somewhat unique in having 4 completely unrelated namespaces.

Hence, why the `new` **MUST** exist. Because if it wasn't there, java wouldn't know which of the 2 relevant namespaces (types, and methods) to dig through. Said differently, this:

```
public class Test {
  public Test() {}
  public static void Test() {}
}
```

is legal java. It compiles fine. So, if import this Test class and then write: `Test();`, which one was I talking about?

In java, it's clear: If you write `new Test()`, it's the constructor, if you write `Test()`, it's the static method.

We can debate at length whether it was a wise idea to have orthogonal namespaces. However, java does not like to break backwards compatibility, and *at this point* changing it all is clearly not worth the pain that would cause, so your question would then boil down to: "Why did the designers of java decide to go with orthogonal namespaces 30 years ago" which.. is hard to answer in an SO question, I'd need a whip and a brown hat, and some John Williams music.

At the class level, those constructors are compiled as special methods, that mostly act like static methods (in that they do not do virtual lookup and do not require a receiver - properties it shares with static methods and it does not with instance methods), named `<init>`. Not `Test` or whatever your class is named.

So, it's best to think of them (As this is really how it works):

- Constructors are constructors. They associate with the type. They **do not have a name**.
- To write a constructor, you repeat the type name and add no return type at all (not even `void` - or you're declaring a method!) - but that's just to let the compiler know what you are doing. Consider the repetition of your type's name as java's way to avoid introducing a keyword (it might as well have been `public constructor(String arg1, int arg2)` instead of `public TypeNameGoesHere(String arg1, int arg2)`, but, it isn't. Again, 30 years, dodge some snakes, if we want to dive into why).

---

NB: The namespaces actually do meet. It's in select AST chains: `a.b.c.d.e` is ambiguous: Is that package `a.b`, then type `c`, with a static inner type named `d`, that has a static field named `e`? Or is it package `a`, with class `b`, inner class `c`, static field `d`, which has type `z` which has an instance field named `e`?

Javac takes its best wild stab in the dark at it during compilation and 'locks it in'. At the runtime (class files) level, truly the namespaces cannot meet. Every instruction makes it clear in which of the 4 namespaces an identifier is referring to.

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of an answer being considered "an opinion" I'd throw out that `java` followed on the heels of C and C++ and essentially inherited the syntax from the latter - even though the analogous `destroy` was unnecessary given the garbage collector.

So there was no strict "requirement" for the `new` but rather following the pattern of the language from which it was most strongly derived.

Comment: From *yshavit's* comment under the question, it seems to serve as a reminder that the object exists on the heap rather than the stack.

Comment: I think this answer gets it right. In C++, it marked an object as being on the heap and needing deletion. In Java, it's vestigial. That's why Kotlin and (recent versions of) Scala have done away with it entirely. It's a pointless distinction in a garbage-collected language.

Comment: I guess so.  Since I'm an a jack of trades and master of no languages, it certainly would help me (if I knew the reason for it!).  In fact, it prompted me to post this question, from which I learned the distinction between stack and heap.  Maybe it needs to be a FAQ.  Since it's on SO, it sort of is a FAQ, though not one that I could find with web searching.

Comment: I think the distinction between heap and stack is useful to non-computer scientists.  Even though all objects are on the heap, at least it reveals to the programmer how Java works.

Answer (score 7):

> Without `new`, for example, it is clear that `MyClass AnInstance = MyClass(AnArgument)` creates a new object.

Is it, though?

Consider this class (which is genuinely valid Java):

```
class ClientOfMyClass {
    // define a method named 'MyClass' that is not a constructor:
    static SubclassOfMyClass MyClass(final String arg) {
        return null;
    }

    String AnArgument = "hello";
    MyClass AnInstance = MyClass(AnArgument);
}
```

In this case, `MyClass(AnArgument)` calls the method named `MyClass` within this class, and never actually creates an instance of `MyClass`.

I think your mistake is in thinking that `new MyClass(AnArgument)` is syntax for calling a constructor named `MyClass`. I would argue that it's not. Instead, it's syntax for creating an instance of `MyClass` by calling an appropriate constructor. As it happens, the syntax for defining constructors involves repeating the class-name; but I don't think we should think of that as the constructor-name. Note that we never write `new MyClass.MyClass(AnArgument)` even though the constructor wouldn't otherwise be in scope, and note that `new MyGenericClass<T>(AnArgument)` passes `T` as the type argument of the class `MyGenericClass`, not its constructor (since constructors don't have type parameters).

Comment: If I misunderstood, I apologize, and would appreciate clarification. It seems to me it that *it doesn't matter*. You get a new object either way, regardless of how it got created. In fact, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47003512) shows how we can get around the need for `new` (see the code containing `getSomeObject`). The *effect* is the same as calling the constructor with `new`, which seems to be what you're doing.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not a developer, so the Java type parameterization isn't something I've gotten to know yet. I'm just trying to get my Java feet under me to support development.

Comment: @user2153235: You have indeed misunderstood, but no need to apologize. I've now edited the snippet to hopefully make it more clear. Re: "the Java type parameterization isn't something I've gotten to know yet": No worries, feel free to ignore that aspect for now.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, a hazard. Does `new` cause the compiler to seek a constructor so that `MyClass` is actually instantiated?  If so, then the criticality of `new` is obvious.

Comment: @user2153235: Strictly speaking, the compiler instantiates the class *before* calling the constructor; but yes, `new MyClass(...)` requires `MyClass` to have an appropriate constructor, which is then called as part of initialization.